# regular expression, not include characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern that looks like this:

```
pattern = '.*class=(.*)'
```

and it gives me the result something like this:

```
my_class=Hello
your_class=Hi
fclass=FHello
class=That's What I need
```

Basically I want to say that I need to return a string that contains `class` only, and not some `fclass my_class` and so on

Comment: please, show the format of the input string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running the regex on individual lines, you can use the `^` symbol to target the beginning of a regex:

```
pattern = r'^class=(.*)'
```

If not, word boundaries might be helpful:

```
pattern = r'\bclass=(.*)'
```